# Different score and best parameter values after using pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline, grid-search

I have a binomial classification problem on the dataset with mixed data,

```
department       category
promoted         category
review            float64
projects            int64
salary           category
tenure            float64
satisfaction      float64
bonus            category
avg_hrs_month     float64
left                int32
dtype: object
```

I have tried to run a DecisionTreeClassifier() with gridsearch and am getting different results depending on whether I use ColumnTransformer() and Pipeline().

with my code without a pipeline, I am getting the best score of 0.925.

```
# encoding ordinal and categorical variables
oe = OrdinalEncoder()
df[["salary","left"]] = oe.fit_transform(df[["salary", "left"]])

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
df[ohe.get_feature_names_out(['department']).tolist()] = ohe.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, :1].values).toarray()
list_of_names = ohe.get_feature_names_out(['department']).tolist()
df[[s.replace("department_", "") for s in list_of_names]] = ohe.transform(df.iloc[:, :1].values).toarray()

df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('department')].copy() 
df

# modelling
cross_val_df, test_df = train_test_split(over_df, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, random_state=32) 
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=32)

parameter_grid = {
  'max_depth':[30, 40, 50, 70], 
  'n_estimators':[ 80, 100, 120, 130, 150]
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, cv=6, param_grid=parameter_grid, scoring='f1').fit(cross_val_df.drop("left", axis=1), cross_val_df["left"])

grid_search.best_params_
{'max_depth': 40, 'n_estimators': 150}
grid_search.best_score_
0.9252745706259379
```

however, with my code with a pipeline, I am getting only 0.599.

```
# encoding ordinal and categorical features
ord_features = ["salary"]
ordinal_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()


cat_features = ["department"]
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")

# column transformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("ord", ordinal_transformer, ord_features),
        ("cat", categorical_transformer, cat_features ),
           ]
)

# pipeline
clf = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())]
)

cross_val_df, test_df = train_test_split(df_over, train_size=0.80, test_size=0.20, random_state=32)

param_grid = {
  'classifier__max_depth':[30, 40, 50,70], 
  'classifier__n_estimators':[ 80, 100, 120, 130, 150]
}


grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid,scoring='f1', cv=6)

grid_search.fit(cross_val_df.drop("left", axis=1), cross_val_df["left"])

grid_search.best_params_
{'classifier__max_depth': 70, 'classifier__n_estimators': 80}

grid_search.best_score_
0.5990146701866147

clf.set_params(**grid_search.best_params_)


clf.fit(cross_val_df.drop("left", axis=1), cross_val_df["left"])

clf.score(test_df.drop("left", axis=1), test_df["left"])
0.514613392526822
```

I am new to pipelines and am trying to understand why my results are different. Thank you.

Comment: Imo you should specify which transformations you're performing to get to the dataset `over_df` in your first example. Then, unless it is a typo, in your second example you're kind of overwriting your `preprocessor`, which I don't think is what you want. Eventually, in your first example you're setting parameter `random_state` to your RFC instance, while in the pipeline you are not.

Comment: added clf = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier(random_state=32))]
).  still different results.

Comment: I expect grid_search.best_score_ to be the same in both cases.

Comment: If you can share the dataset, that would make debugging much easier.  One thing to try: how does the `cross_val_df` in your first approach compare to the output of `preprocessor.fit_transform(cross_val_df)` in your second approach?  Is the dataset ordered?  What happens if you shuffle before splitting?

Answer (score 1):

There are three things that I see.

1. In your first example, you are fitting the `OrdinalEncoder` and the `OneHotEncoder` on the full dataset. This is something you should avoid doing, you should always fit it using the training set. Otherwise, your evaluation is not fair as there might be features present in the overall data that are not part of your training set. This means you are leaking information.
2. That is something I am not sure about, but it looks as if you are passing over_df to train_test_split and not the transformed data frame df. If those are the same, then you can ignore that answer but that is not obvious from your code.
3. In the pipeline, you will only use the features department and salary, as all other columns will be dropped by the ColumnTransformer step. However, in your first example, it looks as if you are using all your columns. Again, this is just what I am expecting to happen but I am not 100% certain from the code you've shared.

Comment: yes, you're correct about 3.   I should have passed remainder='passthrough' in  my ColumnTransformer() to keep all of the columns. Also,  I should also have passed the order of my salary feature, OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['low', 'medium', 'high']]).  with these, I was able to get the same answer.